# Vmss agent pool not getting jobs assigned in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have created a Azure DevOps pipeline. I create a Agent Pool(testpool) and add a virtual machine scale set(VMSS) agent in that pool. The VMSS agent is authorised to use a VMSS in a subscription.
[image]

I pass the pool name(testpool) to the pipeline.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - dev
  
resources:
- repo: self
 
stages:
- stage: Build
  pool:
    name: ${pool}
  displayName: Build and push stage to Dev Branch
```

I verify the variable is passed.
When i run the build i notice that the build job always gets assigned with the already existing default **Azure Pipelines** pool and not my self hosted VMSS Agent pool. My self hosted pool is in idle state.

[image: (]

Can anyone help me? thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

in one of the jobs, i had this line

```
pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
```

This was causing the default **Azure Pipelines** pool to be used when i removed it the self hosted pool was used